# Providing a `malloc` implementation for `newlib-nano`

Tags: c, libc, newlib

I'd like to provide an implementation of `malloc` for `newlib-nano` when using it with `gcc`. In my situation, I have some source file, say `main.c`, that calls `strftime`. The `newlib-nano` implementation of `strftime` uses `malloc`. In a header file, `my_memory.h`, I've declared a function `void *malloc(size_t size)` and provided an implementation in a corresponding `my_memory.c` file.

When linking the project using `gcc`, the linker fails at `.../libc_nano.a(liba-malloc.o)` because of multiple definitions of `malloc`. The behavior I'd like is for the linker to take my implementation of `malloc` rather than pulling `newlib-nano`'s, but to retain using `newlib-nano`'s implementation of other standard library functions, e.g. `memset`.

I've searched around for an "exclude object file from static library" option in gcc to try to exclude `libc_nano.a(liba-malloc.o)` but with no luck. Note that the compiler is pulling in this object file and I don't have access to the compiler's `libc_nano.a` to patch `liba-malloc.o` with my own object file.

Anyway, am I missing something, or is it not possible to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: You can replace their source file with yours but your mileage may vary with that. Their `malloc` is most likely more efficient and feature-rich and yours anyway.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I don't have access to the compiler's object file from the `libc_nano.a` shared library, and I don't have access to the source, so I'm not sure how this would work?

Comment: Ah. Then you can't. Handwritten code is probably more prone to bugs anyway; their implementation is most likely much more tested than yours is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely `liba-malloc.o` contains other allocator function definitions like `calloc`, `free`, `realloc`, etc. and thus is getting pulled in for linking because of references to one of them. You can see this with the `-t` option to `ld` (pass `-Wl,-t` on `gcc` command line when linking to use it). If this is the case, you can avoid linking it just by ensuring you've provided definitions of all these functions yourself.

A better idea might be getting rid of the `malloc` dependency by using a different `strftime`. It's rather ridiculous for `strftime`, especially an embedded-oriented implementation, to be calling `malloc`; it has no fundamental need to and I'm somewhat baffled how they found a way to make `malloc` useful to it. Aside from some tie-in with locale which could be extricated fairly easily, [musl libc's `strftime.c`](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/time/strftime.c?id=v1.1.24) (disclosure: author=me) is very self-contained and could probably serve as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer, and thanks for the work you do on musl libc!

Answer (score 0):

The ST supplied `libc.a` is not weak so the objects in it cannot be simply replaced. You have to weaken it first using `objcopy`, as described on [the eevblog.com forum](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/programming/st-cube-gcc-how-to-override-a-function-not-defined-as-weak-(no-sources)/msg4321462/#msg4321462)